# Alternative to map in marklogic

Tags: database, marklogic

In my application I need to feed billions of entries in map which is taking much time for execution, can there be any other alternative to map which takes less execution time?

Answer (score 2):

With billions of anything, the answer is probably to put them into the database and work with them using range indexes. It might be appropriate to use https://github.com/marklogic/semantic/ or at least borrow some of its concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Justin that more details would help to give a more accurate answer..

In general the main issue with map:map is that it needs to be initialized at each execution of the module. With many entries it is wise to store the map:map entirely somewhere, to speed this up. You could put it in a server-field, so it would only need to be recalculated after a restart. You could also store it in a database, but that would require a database round-trip to retrieve it.

However, a map:map with a billion entries might not perform well at all. As an alternative you could store each entry as a separate document in the database. MarkLogic can handle that very well. You can use cts functions to retrieve appropriate entries. Indexes are kept in memory to make using them *very* fast..

HTH!